Firefox isn't upgraded on Debian: its ESR has 1.5 years old, ensuring it being discarded. How to ask a global upgrade from Debian or Mozilla team?
On my Debian 12 system, installed by default with a Firefox browser managed by Debian in terms of apt updates and upgrades, I went on Slack web site and learned that my Firefox version wasn't supported anymore since September 2024, 1st.

It's normal:

I have a 115.15.0esr version of September 3rd, 2024 considering the security fixes,
but of July, 2023, considering its major version 115.
When the current release of Firefox on its downloading page is 130.x or more.
I have three choices:

Like most users, abandon Firefox and go to Chrome.

Uninstall my Firefox instance, and follow the support mozilla link , hoping that it will work, and that I won't loose all my favorites and customization.
Here is the procedure they suggest to use to perform this:



To install the .deb package through the APT repository, do the
following:

Create a directory to store APT repository keys if it doesn't exist:
sudo install -d -m 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings 


Import the Mozilla APT repository signing key:
wget -q https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/repo-signing-key.gpg -O- | 
   sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc > /dev/null 



If you do not have wget installed, you can install it with: sudo apt-get install wget

The fingerprint should be 35BAA0B33E9EB396F59CA838C0BA5CE6DC6315A3. You may check it with the
following command:
gpg -n -q --import --import-options import-show  /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc | awk '/pub/{getline; gsub(/^ +| +$/,""); if($0 =="35BAA0B33E9EB396F59CA838C0BA5CE6DC6315A3") print "\nThe key  fingerprint matches ("$0").\n"; else print "\nVerification failed: the  fingerprint ("$0") does not match the expected one.\n"}' 


Next, add the
Mozilla APT repository to your sources list:
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list > /dev/null 


Configure APT to prioritize packages from the Mozilla repository:
echo '
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org 
Pin-Priority: 1000 ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla


Update your package list, and install the Firefox .deb package:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox



Set up different languages in Firefox with .deb files
For those of you who would like to use Firefox in a different language than American English, we have also created .deb packages containing the Firefox language packs. To install a specific language pack, replace fr in the example below with the desired language code:
sudo apt-get install firefox-l10n-fr

To list all the available language packs, you can use this command after adding the Mozilla APT repository and running sudo apt-get update:
apt-cache search firefox-l10n


Even if I can process these commands, most of Debian users using Firefox won't know that they are available or dare attempt to run them, keeping an obsolete and less and less usable version of their browser.

So, for Debian 12 users' sake, it seems important to me that this version changes.
I'd like to ask for an upgrade of the Firefox major version delivered through the classical apt-get dist-upgrade install to all Debian 12 users, for convenience.
But how and of whom should I ask that?

Of the Debian team? Following which link?

Or of the Mozilla Foundation, in case it's them who are delivering what to install to a Debian process that is passive?




Thanks! It looks difficult to keep things like they are.
Having an obsolete Browser installed by default on Debian 12 is not good.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Firefox 128esr was published in Debian 12 on October 4, 2024 (and in Debian 11).
The general rule is that, when you find an issue in Debian, you should report it to Debian. In this instance:
reportbug firefox-esr

and file a wishlist bug asking for an update to 128esr. (There is no such bug currently; see the list of firefox-esr bugs.)
The reason issues should be reported to Debian is that you aren’t expected to know whether a problem you notice is caused by something specific to Debian. Obviously, if you determine that it isn’t, then you can skip the Debian part, for example if you find a bug in a program and reproduce it with a “purely upstream” version of the program. However, even in such cases, some action will be required to fix the issue in Debian too, so it’s still worth reporting the issue in Debian.

Thanks again! Submitted as https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1082590

It looks like Slack is wrong and this is a current version:-
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-esr-release-cycle

@deep64blue it is a current version, but that’s not part of Slack’s criteria — they drop support for browser versions 18 months after release (of the major version). In any case 115esr is going to stop being officially supported soon on Linux.

In that case the issue should be raised with Slack then as it seems they are flagging this release prematurely?

Note that " A new upstream version is available: 128.2.0esr" is the first "action needed" listed at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/firefox-esr. I doubt the package maintainers are not aware that there's a new version.

@StéphaneChazelas on top of that, the Firefox maintainer in Debian works for Mozilla. However a notice about a new upstream version isn’t quite the same as a bug report listing sites where the current version no longer works (or is no longer supported), I think the latter is useful nonetheless. (IME quite a few package maintainers don’t pay much attention to the tracker either, so seeing something there isn’t a guarantee that the package maintainer has seen it to — this is just a general comment, I don’t know whether it’s true for the Firefox packages.)

In any case, even after 115 is eol by mozilla wouldn't Debian stable and oldstable still keep 115 and backport security fixes like they do for most other software so as to keep a stable interface? Or would firefox get a special treatment?

@StéphaneChazelas browsers in general get special treatment, along with their supporting ecosystems (Rust and clang in particular). Chromium tracks all upstream releases in stable because there’s no “ESR-style” branch there; Firefox tracks ESR as far as possible but bumps to the next ESR when necessary.

Note that firefox-esr is not mainline firefox.
ESR is "Extended Stable Release" from mozilla and will typically run a few versions behind mainline.  New major versions of ESR are released yearly.
The latest major version of ESR is 128.0 and was released in July, 75 days ago; the version before that was 115.  128.2 (latest bugfix version) was only 19 days ago.
Mozilla still supports 115 (it's in transition state) and 115.15.0 is the latest version of that (from Sep 3rd), so Debian is up to date on its version of ESR; it's not (yet) an obsolete version.
Now I don't see 128 in testing or unstable, so it's possible the Debian team haven't picked up on this yet; it may be worth reporting this to them (eg using reportbug as Stephen Kitt mentioned).  It will be up to them to determine if the 128 version will replace 115 in "bookworm" or if it will go into the backports repo.

Last apt-get dist-upgrade (I've executed this morning) conveniently installed the 128esr, so we are ok for now!

Thanks for following up!

Indeed, the version of Firefox that comes with Debian 12 is Firefox 115.15.0 ESR and this cannot be changed (at least easily). Unless you know what you are doing, I would personally NOT recommand to uninstall this version of Firefox from your computer with the goal of installing the latest one from the Mozilla repos.
However, what you can do is to install, additionally, Firefox Developer Edition which is pretty similar to the regular Firefox. Those two installations can coexist as Mozilla designed it so. You can choose to install Firefox from Mozilla builds with a Local Firefox installation in user's account. Follow the instructions on the page. You can download the French version or any other version. Note: Firefox Dev will update itself automatically when needed (like on Windows).
You will need to create a .desktop file if you want to pin the icon in the taskbar once it's launched. If you are using KDE and Wayland, you may need to follow those instructions in order to fix the bad icons in the taskbar.
That's the way I did it on one of my computers. Hope this will help you.

The current version of firefox on my linux machine is 130. I need to restart firefox to install the latest download.

Go to the mozilla firefox page https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/

Download the latest version of firefox for your OS.

Every once in a while, you will be prompted to download a later version and restart firefox. You can do that at your convenience.


